# Installing Ubuntu on a machine with no screen

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, installation, display

I currently have Windows XP on a laptop, but the screen has died so I use a monitor connected to it to use the laptop. I want to replace the install of Windows XP with the latest Ubuntu but when I boot from the Ubuntu CD it doesn't use the secondary screen.

Does anyone know if this is possible to sort out?

Comment: Does your laptop has hardware key (for example FN+F5) to switch output to monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the laptop is there a Fn + Fkey e.g Fn + F11. If so have you tried pressing this to force the display onto the scondary monitor?

Comment: There is, but on rebooting it forgets that and I'm guessing the Ubuntu install (or simply the CD being in the drive) has a timeout or menu before loading Windows XP again...

Comment: DO you know what the key is to force a boot choice menu. e.g F9 once this was clicked you would have a little longer to click the 2 keys. FN + x

Comment: Had another play it and eventually this worked, many thanks. It was odd that the F key+ thing didn't work first of all, just seemed to happened when it started loading Windows. Anyway, al good now, I can put the laptop on ebay for spares!